# WPF: How to combine animations with custom event handling?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a custom WPF control that is draggable, but I also need to animate it as it is dragged. I need to override OnMouseDown to implement the dragging functionality, but I also want my animation triggered on the MouseDown event.

Without dragging functionality--i.e., when OnMouseDown is not overriden--the animation works, but when I override OnMouseDown to implement the dragging functionality, the animation stops working.

What's the trick here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I'm using PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown instead of overriding OnMouseDown to start dragging operations.